# Simple RC Problem

Tags: circuit-design

I'm trying to figure out a simple RC circuit problem. So I have a resistor and capacitor running in parallel. My resistor is 6 and my capacitor is C. Now what I want to know is how to retain the same impedance of that system if I changed the resistor value to 3 ohms. What do I have to C to obtain that same impedance?

Comment: Did you have a specific frequency in mind?

Comment: I don't think a specific frequency would matter, but 60 htz ought to do it.

Comment: If you don't have a specific frequency in mind, you can simply use complex ohm's law with the capacitor's reactance parametricized as a function of omega.

Comment: The same impedance or the same magnitude of impedance?

Comment: If you want the same time constant on your filter then you could half the resistor and double the capacitor

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

It's easier to understand why if you think about admittance instead of impedance. There is a 1-to-1 correspondence between admittance and impedance because admittance is just the inverse of impedance:

$$Y=\frac{1}{Z}$$

So for two networks to have the same impedance, they must have the same admittance.

Now, in the case of a resistor and capacitor in parallel, the admittance is given by

$$Y=\frac{1}{R}+j\omega C$$

The key point is the real part is determined solely by \$R\$ and the imaginary part is determined solely by \$C\$.

So if you change \$R\$ you change the real part of the admittance. And no change in the capacitance can change it back to the previous value.

Comment: Perhaps put your comment about magnitude into this reply?

Comment: @Neil_UK, for now I'm just answering the question that was asked. If OP changes to just want magnitude, I'll add it.